# html - css block Width/Height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
#nav {}
#nav a { 
         position: relative;
         display: inline-block;
         color: #F0F0F0;
         width: 1em;
         height: 2em;
         line-height: 0.9em;
}
#nav a.icon:before { padding-right: 0;} 

<nav id="nav">
  <a href="#me" class="fa fa-home active"><span>Home</span></a>
</nav>
```

But if the text is longer than 10 characters, it is automatically making a paragraph, making the text out of the original box. How can I prevent this?

---

Edit

---

All i want the background box in the screenshot to get bigger in width as the text is longer

http://prntscr.com/2cd973

Comment: Do you want js-code making a paragraph if more than 10 characters?

Comment: Are you saying that it *is* making a paragraph and you wish it wouldn't, or that it isn't and you wish it would?

Comment: Have you tried something like `overflow:hidden;`, this will cut the text off when the container is filled

Comment: I don't see your aim do you want to hide the text if it is too big or do you want to display it all on the same line?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle depicting your issue..unclear

Comment: All i want is this box to get bigger if text is longer.
http://prntscr.com/2cd973
screenshoted cause i can't explain it very well. english not native language.
ty in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your aim is to display it all on the same line, you just need to remove `width:1em;` from `#nav a`

if you want to hide the text that is overflowing add `overflow:hidden;` to `#nav a`

if you want the `a` tag to adapt height and width to its content remove `width:1em;` and `height:2em;` from `#nav a`

Comment: I tryed your solution but i still get this
http://prntscr.com/2cd8bx
I don't really know what to do anymore

Comment: Could you be clear about what your aim is I can see on your screenshot that the text is overflowing but what do you want do do with it? hide it? put it all on the same line? and if you could provide a fiddle it would be awesome

Comment: All i want the background box in the screenshot to get bigger in width as the text is longer.
dunno how to represent it in the fiddle, cause box is drawn with js

Comment: Is it possible to resize the text as it gets longer to fit the box?

Comment: whitch tag is the background set to? and do you have an online example?

Comment: www.aroundgalaxy.pt/NEW
ill haply send you the files so you could review the code.
thanks for tanking your time to try to solve my problem btw

Comment: Nevermind, i found this
/* Labels not wide enough? Increase its width below and set margin-left to ((width / 2) * -1) */
God, sorry guys for taking your time

Comment: @willier for you specific example you can set width:10em and margin-left:-5em on #nav a span

Answer (score 1):

You can display your content as a `table-row`. Then your links will be displayed as new columns in a table.

```
#nav {
    display: table-row;
}
```

You can see the results on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6qXq/).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in **#nav** :

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```